# What's the next action I should take with this rootbound plant?

Tags: roots, root-pruning

After some help with what I should do with this plant, I've neglected to check its roots of for some time. I believe it to be a species of asparagus grass, though if someone wants to correct that belief feel free.

As you can see from the images, I may have left the roots alone for too long (in fact I had to literally cut the old plant pot away from the bottom of it, because they'd grown through and formed a circle underneath it The plant itself seems to be fine (in-fact flowered for the first time in the 6-ish years I've had it, though they were very small, and dropped off at the slightest touch).

Is the answer to the question ["How do I prune the roots of a rootbound plant?"](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2968/how-do-i-prune-the-roots-of-a-rootbound-plant) still appropriate with such a root-locked plant? What's the next size up pot to put it in? It was in a 6' (I think, the next up is a 7' at any rate) pot.

[image: Root Shot]
[image: Full plant Shot]

Answer (score 2):

The answer you mention is a very detailed one and is still appropriate. Keep in mind that many houseplants, like your [asparagus fern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asparagus_plumosus), will only flower when they are pot bound.

With a healthy plant like yours you can take some quick action with a sharp knife and be done in minutes and still be friends afterwards....

Cut off the bottom one third to one quarter of the root ball.  For the remaining root ball make three or four vertical cuts to a depth of about one inch (two cm).  Place fresh soil in the bottom of the pot to make up for what you cut away and replant.

When selecting a new pot pick the same size or one size up.  A heavily pot bound plant will require some attention to watering after treatment.  The new soil will stay wetter longer until the roots grow into it.  Ensure you water the complete root ball not just the new soil.

This recommendation will work on healthy plants with good exposure to sunlight. It would be a little harsh for plants without a well developed root system or ones in low light.